# Why is replacing an element of a vector so slow?

Tags: c++, c++11

I notice that amending (or replacing) an element in a large vector is consuming a lot of time when the vector is getting bigger, even when the element's place in the vector is known.

Is there an explanaition for this?

I use an unsorted set as an index. The code first tries to find the element in the set with set.find(). If the element not present in the set the code insert it at the end of the set and at the same time pushes it at the end of the vector. 
If the element is found on position "x" of the set the data in the vector is replaced by using:

```
vector.at(x)=vector[x]+element.
```

When I skip the vector part and only insert the element in the set the code easily processes 95 million elements in less then 2 minutes. But when I add the vector part to it the code keeps on running for hours.

The file I'm importing is a semicolumn separated text, with below structure

```
2161182;Jutfaseweg;footway;no;7740068,13877901
2953564;Timorkade;cycleway;no;7785429,368846814,582743212,582743202,582743213,582743203,582743214,582743206,582743210,45200603
```

Each line represents a way. The ID's in the last element are waypoints of that particular way. Each element has a righthand neighbour, unless it is the last element of the way and based on the 4th element ("yes" or "no", meaning oneway or not), also a lefthand neighbour, unless it is the first element of the way.

Below is the code as requested

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <set>    
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

set<string>PresentStreet;
set<int>PresentNode;
vector<string>NeighBours;
string line1;

void split(const string& s, char c,
           vector<string>& v) {
   string::size_type i = 0;
   string::size_type j = s.find(c);

   while (j != string::npos) {
      v.push_back(s.substr(i, j-i));
      i = ++j;
      j = s.find(c, j);

      if (j == string::npos)
         v.push_back(s.substr(i, s.length()));
   }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  ifstream myfile ("filename.txt");
      int CounterLine=1;
  while ( getline (myfile,line1) ) {
    string s1=line1;
    vector<string> v1;
    split(line1, ';', v1);
    PresentStreet.insert(v1[2]); 

    vector<string> v2;
    split(v1[4], ',', v2);

    for (int t=0;t<v2.size();t++) {

          auto search = PresentNode.find(atoi(v2[t].c_str()));
          if(search == PresentNode.end()) {

                    string Neighbours="";
          if(v1[3].find("no")!=std::string::npos&&t>0) {  
            Neighbours=Neighbours+v2[t-1]+",";
          }
          if(t<v2.size()-1) {
            Neighbours=Neighbours+v2[t+1]+",";
          }

        stringstream ss;
        ss<<CounterLine;
        stringstream ss2;
        ss2<<v2[t];          
        PresentNode.insert(atoi(v2[t].c_str()));
        NeighBours.push_back(Neighbours);
      }else{
        int nPosition = distance (PresentNode.begin (), search);
        string Neighbours=NeighBours[nPosition];
          if(v1[3].find("no")!=std::string::npos&&t>0) {  
            Neighbours=Neighbours+v2[t-1]+",";
          }
          if(t<v2.size()-1) {
            Neighbours=Neighbours+v2[t+1]+",";
          }
        NeighBours.at(nPosition)=Neighbours;
      }
    }CounterLine++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Good chance that the replace is causing the entire vector beyond the replace to be "moved".  I'll leave it to others more skilled in C++11 than I to tell the magic incantation to fix this.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: Not the replace, but the push back.

Comment: I think we're going to need to see some more code. What you posted, for one, doesn't compile. Also, you are doing an addition between the vector and the new element?

Comment: How much memory does your system have, and how large are the elements you're storing in the vector? Are they small like integers, or are the bigger like some composite type? Also, it would really really help if you posted some code that illustrates the problem. In particular, we could use the code that defines your data type and code that implements the algorithm you describe above.

Comment: What is the definition of `vector`? Is it a vector of `int`?

Comment: Which implementation of set are you using? std::set is sorted, while std::unordered_set is keyed by hash of the value - in either case you won't be able to insert element *at the end* of the set. Pushing back elements to vector assuming that elements are inserted at the end of the set would mess up your indexing, unless you are using some custom implementation of set.

Comment: What type does the vector contain? Is it expensive to copy? Is it movable? Do you know the maximum size of the vector up-front? Can you provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: The code provided does not compile as written.  You can test this by copy-pasting it into an editor, watching it not compile.  Please produce code that compiles as written (ideally after making your code minimal), then test that the problem still occurs in the minimal, compiling code.  I am not going to fix not-compiling code, then work out what you mean by what is going wrong, determine if it is going wrong, and maybe find out that your sample code doesn't actually display the symptoms you claim.  You clearly did not, as the code you posted could not have been compiled by you either.

Comment: @Yakk, I have rewritten the code and compiled it with VS2010. This did work. Apologises for providing an incorrect code in the first place. However my question is actually if it's normal that amending data in a vector (type string) is taking so long, even if the place of the element in the vector is known

Comment: why don't you just edit `NeighBours[nPosition];` in-place instead of copying the string out, modifying, and copying back in (which will cause several more allocations/deallocations).  Using two `+=` instead of `+`...`+` may be an improvement also.

Comment: `vector.at(x)=vector[x]+element` would be a mistake. Luckily your code actuall does not contain that...

Comment: @HB1963 A word of advice, you probably want to use more descriptive and less confusing variable names. You have a std::vector named `NeighBours` and two std::string named `Neighbours`.

Comment: a performance tip for vectors, try to do a `reserve` of the final size, before you do a lot of `push_back`'s

Comment: @HB1963, are you building a 32bit or 64bit target, and have you observed the memory usage/availability of your system while running this? I ask because you state 95million in 2 minutes.

Comment: [If push_back() can invalidate iterators and references](http://en.cppreference.com/w/Talk:cpp/container/vector/push_back), do you think that could explain the longer time? Looping through something that you are `insert`ing and `push_back`ing will increase the loop time. 

Also, could `.find()` be contributing to the slowness as well? Since it is does a linear search, it can get slow if the number of items is very large (and you mentioned 95 million).

I'm sorry if these are ignorant or irrelevant comments.

Comment: @sp2danny, as I do want to make the code as flexible as possible I do not want to reverve upfront as the number of items may vary

Comment: @bratak, `.find()` is not the problem. If I run the code without the vector part (`NeighBours.at(nPosition)=Neighbours;`) it runs within 2 minutes. However adding ths one piece of code causes the code to run for hours